# Using React native Picker to display fetched array

Tags: react-native, picker

I m using fetch to get a data of arrays, and i push them into one array so i could display them as my react native picker items, this my code:

```
state = {
    selectedValue: '',
    data : []
   
  };
 componentDidMount() {
    
    return fetch('****url')
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((res) => {
            let da = [];
            var count = Object.keys(res.proches).length;
            for(var i=0;i<count;i++){
              da.push(res.proches[i][0].nom ); 
            }
            
            
            this.setState({
              data:da
            })
            
            
        })
        .done();
  }
 render() {
    console.log("!!!!!!!!!")
    console.log(this.state.data);
    return (
        <Picker
           selectedValue={this.state.selectedValue}
           onValueChange={() =>{}} >
           { this.state.data.map((item, index)=>
             <Picker.Item label={item} value={index} key={index}/>
           )}
         </Picker>
```

and this is what console.log(this.state.data) shows:
[image]

but my picker doesn't display anything neither open up, what have i done wrong?
thanks for your replies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is a styling issue.
try to give him style:

```
<Picker 
    selectedValue={this.state.selectedValue}
    style={{ height: 50, width: 100 }}
    onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => setSelectedValue(itemValue)}
>
    { 
        this.state.data.map((item, index) => <Picker.Item label={item} value={index} key={index} />)
    }
</Picker>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this lightweight and completely customizable package [rn-multipicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rn-multipicker)

Full article: https://dev.to/rahull04/add-multi-select-dropdown-to-react-native-applications-53ef

```
import { RNMultiSelect } from 'rn-multipicker';

const COUNTRIES = [
"Afghanistan",
"Albania",
"Algeria",
"American Samoa",
"Andorra",
"Angola",
"Anguilla",
"Antarctica",
"Antigua and Barbuda",
"Argentina",
];

const App() {
  const [selectedItems, setSelectedItems] = useState<string[]>([]);

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
       <RNMultiSelect placeholder="Countries" data={COUNTRIES} onSelectedItemsChange={(value) => setSelectedItems(value)} selectedItems={selectedItems} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

[Linkedin Post](https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:activity:7150528727720820736?utm_source=share&utm_medium=member_desktop)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35517009)